# Unable to read a mainframe generated file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ebcdic

I am trying to read a mainframe generated file using the following code: The end goal is to load it into a dataframe.

```
import codecs

with open(r'C:\Users\743622\Downloads\UC005\USA.CKN.D050920', "rb") as ebcdic:
    ascii_txt = codecs.decode(ebcdic, "cp500")
    print(ascii_txt)
```

I get the following error in doing so:

```
----> 5     ascii_txt = codecs.decode(ebcdic, "cp500")
      6     print(ascii_txt)
      7 

TypeError: decoding with 'cp500' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader')
```

I am also trying to add a glimpse of what the input file looks like in notepad++.[image: Snapshot of data in notepad++]

Comment: in your code, `ebcdic` is just a handle for the file. you still need to *read* the bytes to be able to decode them. something like `ascii_txt = codecs.decode(ebcdic.read(), "cp500")`. side-note: what's the relation to `pandas`? please don't use inadequate tags.

Comment: HI MrFuppes, could you please advise how to load it into a dataframe. I am not getting the same error as before so I hope it is reading something. I used pandas tag because end goal is to load a dataframe.  The .read() statement worked it seems.

Comment: does `print(ascii_txt)` show what you expect? suppose I can't say more without sample data.

Comment: @PawanTolani, were you able to transform? can you please help me, I have similar task to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data shown in the Notepad++ screen shot show a lot of *NUL* characters, i.e. x'00' values. This indicates that the mainframe file does **not** consist of printable character only, but also contains binary data. This is quite normal with mainframe files.

I have transformed the first few characters to EBCDIC

```
ÃÒÕ.....€..".ÆÅÙÙÅÙÖ@ÙÁÆÆÁÅÓÓÖ
```

The sequence '.....' is `NULNULNULEOTNUL`, and the sequence '..".' is `NULNUL"SI`.

The result is

```
'CKN' '0000000400800000220F'x 'FERRERO RAFFAELLO'
```

That is three characters, followed by a 10 byte binary sequence, followed by another character string.

My point is, you **cannot** simply transform this file from ASCII to EBCDIC. You need to understand which bytes are EDCDIC characters, and which bytes are binary data. For the latter, you also need to understand this binary data in more detail. The provider of this mainframe file should be able to tell you how the records are built.

Comment: Hey @phunsoft could you please explain how did you actually convert the first few characters of EBCDIC to `'CKN' '0000000400800000220F'x 'FERRERO RAFFAELLO'`

Comment: @Surya I'm sorry, I can't remember the details after that long time. I probably typed the string into notepad++, the looked at it in hex display. Then took an EBCDIC code page, and looked up the hex values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the file content to `codecs.decode` not the "file object".

try this: `ascii_txt = codecs.decode(ebcdic.read(), "cp500")`

Comment: The above is working (albeit with a warning that can be handled). Can someone please help with building a dataframe out of it?

Comment: No sorry. I have no idea about pandas.

Comment: how can I just save the decoded output into a text file? I tried multiple things but it doesnt work!